# Xpath not just getting parent of html

Tags: xpath

I am trying to find the xpath for only the parent of a navigation bar. The path which I am trying at the moment is `//a[@class='unselectable'] from this peace of HTML.

```
`<div class="PrimaryNavigationContainer">
                <div class="PrimaryNavigation">   
        <div class="Menu">   

        <div>    
        <a href="http://www.blah.co.uk/brands.aspx" class="unselectable"><span>
                                    Brands</span></a>
         <div class="navCol">
         <div>
             <a class="NoLink unselectable"><span>Shop by Brand</span></a>
             <div class="navCol subMenus">
              div>                  
          <a href="http://www.blah.co.uk/blah/catlist_bd4.htm" class="unselectable"><span>
                                                blah</span></a>
```

The xpath seem to be bringing up both the top level cats and sub categories and I am because it is in both but not sure how to single of the parent from the chld. Thanks for any help which you can provide

Comment: Please edit your question and paste valid formatted HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `//div[@class="Menu"]/div/a[@class='unselectable']`? This way you avoid selecting the `a` in the `subMenus` div.